# Array or database Table? Store the temporary data in memory array or database?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have about 300 lines of 60 characters. Can I download them directly in an array, or a better use of the database sqlite? whether memory will sustain? How better to describe the type of optimization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking at
300(Strings) * 60(characters) * 2bytes(per character) = 36KB

I believe android limits applications to 12MB in memory? So you're using 0.3% of your memory capacity by using an array. I'd say that's well within budget.

Comment: How better to describe the type of data?

Comment: ArrayList<String> = new ArrayList<>();    ? Is that what you're asking?

Comment: is there any type of string[60] ? =)

Comment: No, there is "String", which contains an array of chars, and it sounds like you have 60 chars per string, and 300 strings.